# Redirecting with a message not working in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-response

I have a following code in my `posts.create` action.

```php
// ...
return redirect(route('posts.index'))->with('flashMessage', 'test');
// ...
```

I expect `$flashMessage` variable to be available in the `posts.index` view, however, it is not. What am I doing wrong?

**P.S**

I don't want to set the flash message using `Session::flash('flashMessage', 'test')`, because it won't work in case of json responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in redirect you have to pass url not route name
add the following code to your blade page

```
@if(Session::has('flashMessage'))
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
      {{ Session::get('flashMessage') }}
  </div>
@endif
```

Comment: The redirecting occurs just fine. There is nothing wrong with the syntax, however the variable is stored in the session indeed, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Seems like your syntax is wrong. Try this one

```
return redirect()->route('posts.index')->with('flashMessage', 'test');
```

Comment: The redirecting occurs just fine. There is nothing wrong with the syntax I use, it's the message that is not passed to the view. Unfortunately, your code doesn't work either